How to get the path of the file selected in <InputFile />? Blazor Server Application
I need to get the path of the file that the user selects in the <input file> event to send the file to the API using FluentFTP. I am using FTP to upload the file to the server. follow the example:
// create an FTP client and specify the host, username and password 
// (delete the credentials to use the "anonymous" account) 
var client = new FtpClient("123.123.123.123", "david", "pass123");
// connect to the server and automatically detect working FTP settings
client.AutoConnect();
// upload a file
client.UploadFile(@"C:\MyVideo.mp4", "/htdocs/MyVideo.mp4");

From my research, there is no way to find the exact path, but I would be grateful if you could give me another solution for this type of situation.

Are you clear about where your code runs?  You are not allowed to know the path on the User's device. And you wouldn't be able to use it anyway.

If upload a file from "InputFile", you could turn the "InputFile" data into a filestream and use UploadStream. 
Even if you have the path, the server cannot access user's computer to get that file. You could try following sample: (modified as Charlieface suggested)
@page "/"
@using FluentFTP
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<InputFile OnChange="LoadFile" />

<button @onclick="Upload" >UpLoad</button>

@code{

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    private async Task LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    }

    private async Task Upload()
    {
        var client = new AsyncFtpClient("123.123.123.123", "david", "pass123");
        await client.AutoConnect();
        await client.UploadStream(memoryStream, "/htdocs/MyVideo.mp4");
    }
}


Using AsyncFtpClient would be wise, then you do await client.AutoConnect(); await client.UploadStream. Having said that, if it's a large file it probably makes sense to upload directly, rather than caching in a MemoryStream
